# How to find the fourth thursday of november for any year?

Tags: c, modulo

I am trying to find the fourth Thursday of November (thanksgiving day) of any user inputted year. I used the following function to find the day of December 31'st of the previous year of user inputted year.

```
int yr;
int lastDayofDecember;
scanf("%i",&yr);
lastDayofDecember = (((yr-1)*365)+((yr-1)/4)-((yr-1)/100)+((yr-1)/400))%7;
```

where, `lastDayofDecember = 0 : Sunday, 1 : Monday,......6:Saturday;`

Now for `year 2016`, the last day was a Saturday i.e `lastDayofDecember = 6`, I added `5` to it to find the first thursday of January and added `304` to it to find the first Thursday of November (January 1 - November 1 is 304 days for non-leap year) to which I added 21 to find the fourth thursday of November, but now I am confused about what to do next. I can not use loops

```
    int txDay = 5 + 304 + 21;
```

Comment: I would construct the date November 1 (for whatever year) in a `struct tm`, then call `mktime` to fill in `tm_wday`, then work from there.

Comment: @SteveSummit: I'd do similar, but using November 21.

Comment: @SteveSummit I can not use `struct` since it is a school assignment. But I am using user defined functions to work this problem out.

Comment: `int thanksGivingDayOfMonth=28-(5+year+year/4-year/100+year/400)%7;` (now you only need to explain this)

Comment: @FelixPalmen this calculates what day is the last day of the given `year`. `0=Sunday`,`1=Monday` and so on till `6=Saturday`.

Comment: @SanMo I think you didn't understand my comment.

Comment: @FelixPalmen Oh I got it now, sorry been up all night trying to figure this out haha

Comment: @SanMo still it only helps you when you **can** explain it. It's not that hard though.

Comment: @FelixPalmen Yes I am trying to figure out the logic behind the code you gave me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @SanMo I added an explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Breaking this down, although it's not directly about programming, it's an interesting topic -- assuming the gregorian calendar only *):

As the week day advances by one per year, it **can** be calculated using a simple modulo 7 of the year. The only problem here are leap years, and you already have the formula to accomodate for these.

You're effectively doing calculations in the [Ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_(mathematics)) **ℤ<sub>7</sub>** so you just have to add the number of leap years until your current year. Exploiting integer division, this number is

```
year/4 - year/100 + year/400
```

So, to get a unique number between 0 and 7 corresponding to one day of week each, you just do `(year + year/4 - year/100 + year/400) % 7`. This would be a bit more complicated for dates early in the year, but as we're interested in November, for leap years, the 29. February has already passed -> nothing more to do.

The latest possible date for thanksgiving day is the 28, when the 1. November is a Friday. So you want your calculated value to be `0` for years when November starts on a Friday. You can find by experimentation that you need to add an offset of `5` inside your Ring to achieve that. With that, you just need to subtract that value from this latest possible date, `28`. This gives the complete formula:

```
int thanksGivingDate = 28 - (5 + year + year/4 - year/100 + year/400) % 7;
```

---

*) As this uses the rules of the gregorian calendar, the result will be **incorrect** for older dates still using the julian calendar. (e.g. 1752 and earlier for the U.S.)